# How to pass Widget to const Constructor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class to store title, body and icon of tabs in my flutter app.

```
class Destination {
  const Destination(
      {this.title,
      this.icon,
      this.color = Colors.blue,
      this.body: const Center(
        child: Text("Example"),
      )});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final MaterialColor color;
  final Widget body;
}
```

and I am trying to create list of all my tabs using

```
const List<Destination> allDestinations = <Destination>[
  Destination(title: 'Calculate', icon: Icons.edit, body: const Calculator()),
  Destination(
    title: 'Detail',
    icon: Icons.details,
  )
];
```

But it keeps showing error that const variables must be initialized with constant value whether I add const or not. `Calculator()` is just StatefulWidget. So I would appreciate any help to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is only one reason, Calculator does not have const constructor.

Comment: @Esen Mehmet you were correct. I'm new to flutter and dart. Can you point me to what I should learn from this mistake? And can you add it to answer so I can mark answered?

Comment: Sure, you can learn const keyword syntax with this example. I'm adding detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said, `Calculator` does not have `const` constructor. Sometimes you can't make the `const` constructors for Widgets. Because the Widget must be `immutable class` which may break your purpose.

In Flutter some widgets have `const constructor` some of them don't have(etc. Column, Row, AnimatedContainer). Usually the reason is they are interactive(both inside and outside).

One another trick in your example, if you put `const` to your `variable`, the right side of assignment `does not need any const`. Because if this variable is const, right side must be const already so no need to define `const` each time.

Same thing valid for also trees, if parent has `const`, child must be const, no need to put another const.

In your example, if `Calculator` had a const constructor, putting const to Calculator won't make any difference.

So this has exact same functionality with yours:

```
const List<Destination> allDestinations = <Destination>[
  Destination(title: 'Calculate', icon: Icons.edit, body: Calculator()),
  Destination(
    title: 'Detail',
    icon: Icons.details,
  )
];
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you make Calculator constructor const:

```
class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calculator({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalculatorState createState() => _CalculatorState();
}
```